# Make a dynamic SCSS method to change variable values

Tags: css, sass

I have done a project with a lot of code duplicity, so the problem occurs because I have to write the class in each query.
I'm trying to improve performance here. In order to do that, I want to use dynamic values for styling.
For example, the way CSS is being used here, but in ten different places using the same animation.

```
$center : 590px;

.container {
  width: $center;
 }

@media only screen and (max-width: 1660px){
//here I want to change $center to 490px;
// =================================================
// but the way that I found is to duplicate it 
$center: 490px;

.container {
  width: $center;
 }
/*note : if I don't call the '.container' everytime that I'm changing the $center variable it does not work,
I have some animations that must use the variables .
*/

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `@mixin` and `@include` to avoid duplication.

```
@mixin media-container($center) {
  @media only screen and (max-width: 1660px) {
    .container {
      width: $center;
    }
  }
}
```

In order to use the `@mixin` in any classes you want, you can add the following to the class you want to use this in:

```
.container-class {
    @include media-container(540px);
}
```

Note that the `540px` above can be replaced with any configuration you want for `$center` variable, which would change the width for your container.

Documentation: https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/mixin

Comment: please look at this maybe you can understand me https://justpaste.it/6w6wf - if you found any soultion for my duplicate please update me as fast as you can

Comment: i just dont want to make a lot of mixins - im trying to make varible that effect all what i typed before a lot of animations

Comment: Do you have a reference for the HTML you're styling?

Comment: please look here : scss - https://justpaste.it/3uifi , html - https://justpaste.it/9jjnt , js - https://justpaste.it/41xc9

Answer (score 0):

SCSS variables are static (compile time) to do what you want you need to use CSSVariables that are dynamic (run time) - something like this

```
.container {
  width: var(--width, 590px); /* default */
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1660px){
  .container { 
     --width: 490px; 
  }
}
```

If you need to set multiple values - you can use Sass nesting
to make it a little easier to type

```
.container {
  width: var(--width, 50px);
  @media (min-width: 100px) { --width: 100px; }
  @media (min-width: 200px) { --width: 200px; }
  @media (min-width: 300px) { --width: 300px; }
  ...
}


// output
.container { 
   width: var(--width, 50px); 
} 
@media (min-width: 100px) { 
  .container { --width: 100px; } 
}
@media (min-width: 200px) { 
  .container { --width: 200px; } 
}
@media (min-width: 300px) { 
  .container { --width: 300px; } 
}
```